# Improving Computer Vision descriptions and tags

Tags: computer-vision

I have been testing the Microsoft Computer Vision API with some pictures I took and it is not able to properly identify what I am uploading. Is there a way I could teach it what I am uploading is?

My tests have been using https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api.

A sample image:

[image]

It should include "bottle" in the tags at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom images or training the module with domain specific models is not yet available for Computer Vision.  They have a enhancement request on their feedback page.

https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-apis/suggestions/13289049-train-the-vision-api-with-custom-tags-domain-speci

Comment: Will try OpenCV and SURF. Thanks!